# Trying to isolate 1 column with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, wikipedia

I am trying to isolate the Location column and then eventually get it to output to a database file. My code is as follows:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ongoing_armed_conflicts"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

trs = soup.find_all('td')

for tr in trs:
  for link in tr.find_all('a'):
    fulllink = link.get ('href')

tds = tr.find_all("tr")
location = str(tds[3].get_text())



print location
```

but I always get 1 of 2 errors either list being out of range or exit code '0'. I am uncertain on beautfulsoup as I am trying to learn it so any help is appreciated thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way to locate the `Location` column. Use a `table.wikitable tr` [CSS Selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), find all `td` elements for every row and get the 4th `td` by index.

Besides, if there are multiple locations inside a cell, you need to treat them separately:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ongoing_armed_conflicts"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

for row in soup.select('table.wikitable tr'):
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if cells:
        for text in cells[3].find_all(text=True):
            text = text.strip()
            if text:
                print text
```

Prints:

```
Afghanistan
Nigeria
Cameroon
Niger
Chad
...
Iran
Nigeria
Mozambique
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply swap `td` and `tr` balises in your code. And be careful with `str()` function because you can have unicode string in your web page that cannot be converted in simple ascii string. Your code should be:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ongoing_armed_conflicts"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

trs = soup.find_all('tr')  # 'tr' instead of td

for tr in trs:
    for link in tr.find_all('a'):
        fulllink = link.get ('href')
        tds = tr.find_all("td")  # 'td' instead of td
        location = tds[3].get_text()  # remove of str function
        print location
```

And *voilà!!*